# Set of $U(6)$ elements which leave a Lie-algebra element invariant under conjugation

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

Consider the specific element of the corresponding Lie algebra $\mathbb{1}_3 \times \sigma^3$, where $\mathbb{1}_3$ is the unit matrix in 3 dimensions, $\sigma^3$ is the 3rd Pauli matrix and $\times$ stands for Kronecker product. I want to find the space
$$
\left\{ U\in U(6) \; \text{ such that} \; U\left( \mathbb{1}_3 \times \sigma^3\right)U^\dagger = \mathbb{1}_3 \times \sigma^3 \right\}.
$$
I am particularly interested in whether this set is connected or disjoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a theorem (of Hopf, I believe) that the centralizer of any member of the Lie algebra (not just $\mathbb{1}_3 \otimes \sigma^3$) is connected. See Bourbaki, Lie groups, Chap. 9, §2, nº2, [Corollary 5](https://books.google.com/books?id=oCO0xOzNLhAC&pg=PA290).

In your case $\mathbb{1}_3 \otimes \sigma^3$ is conjugate to $\smash[b]{\begin{pmatrix}\mathbb{1}_3&0\\0&-\mathbb{1}_3\end{pmatrix}}$ and so the centralizer is conjugate to the diagonal $U(3)\times U(3)$.

Comment: by conjugate do you mean it is related by a conjugation?

Comment: yes (conjugation by the appropriate permutation matrix).

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps you know the answer to this sort of follow up...
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407235/set-of-su6-matrices-which-conjugate-a-mathfraksu2-subalgebra-element